# Optimization: Use “between” or “>= and <=”

Tags: oracle, optimization, between

Let’s take the following question, for example. Is there any difference between using:

```
SELECT * FROM foo_table 
WHERE column BETWEEN n and m
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM foo_table 
WHER column>=n and column<=m?
```

Looks like a simple one,Oracle’s documentation is dead clear on this:

[Between] means “greater than or equal to low value and less than or equal to high value.”

They are the same from a semantic point of view. But, SQL is a declarative language. So,  you wouldn’t expect same execution plan with two semantically identical statements, right?

My Questions are:

- An optimizer might watch for a different code path for equal or less than versus less than on a numeric index, right?
- What is better and faster way for Numeric types?

Comment: Have you tried running them with explain? What did you find?

Comment: I tried this, same explain plan, same cost

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.3.0      Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: Have you tried searching for possible articles on the topic? http://www.orafaq.com/node/1798 or http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle's optimizer converts `between` to `>=` and `<=`, which you can see from the execution plan. For example, this is from 11gR2:

```
explain plan for
select * from dual where dummy between 'W' and 'Y';

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

--------------------------------------------------------------------------       
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------       
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------       

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                              
---------------------------------------------------                              

   1 - filter("DUMMY">='W' AND "DUMMY"<='Y')
```

Notice the `filter` being used. So it makes no difference which you use, except perhaps in edge cases like [the article this seems to have come from](http://www.pythian.com/blog/oracle-can-between-and-greater-than-or-equal-to-and-less-than-or-equal-to-differ/) (thanks Shankar). Worrying about it for mainstream cases probably isn't going to be on much benefit.

Comment: It does make a difference, in specific cases though - http://www.pythian.com/blog/oracle-can-between-and-greater-than-or-equal-to-and-less-than-or-equal-to-differ/

Comment: @Shankar - interesting - both the behaviour and that the question seems to have been lifted from that article. Well found.